# URLEncode return different value in ASP classic and PHP

Tags: php, url-encoding

I'm developing and application which must integrate with PayPal. To do so, it makes some call via API, and in these calls I have to pass some parameters that are URLEncoded. My problem is that I don't get it working because Server.URLEncode of classic asp returns me something strange.

See bellow:

```
@CODEPAGE="65001"    
Response.Charset = "UTF-8"
response.write(server.URLEncode("xxxx_1344559025_biz_api1.yy.com"))
```

Returns me this string: xxxx%5F1344559025%5Fbiz%5Fapi1%2Eyy%2Ecom

The same in PHP

```
echo(urlencode('xxxx_1344559025_biz_api1.yy.com'));
```

Returns me this string:xxxx_1344559025_biz_api1.yy.com

Both files are encoded in UTF-8, I do that on DreamWeaver with CTRL+J > title/encoding

Does anyone know why I get a so different answer in ASP classic and PHP?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: ASP's going a bit overboard and encoding the `.` and `_` characters. Those aren't URL metacharacters so there's no real reason they should be encoded.

Answer (score 1):

The ASP version of URLEncode is just stricter than the PHP version.

Some characters, like the dot or the underscore do not absolutely need to be encoded (as opposed to the ampersand or the equals sign, which could break the query string if left unencoded).

I suppose for the reason of producing less "ugly" URLs, PHP leaves these characters unencoded, as they do no harm, while ASP stricly encodes everything that's not an ASCII alphanumeric.

In the end there will be no difference between the strings.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I will try to find a way to deal with it.

Comment: @André: I just wrote a function that replaces the `%5F` back to `_` and so on.